# Generic in ForEach?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

Good day. Guys, tell me how to get data in ForEach if I pass an array there in generic?
I want to make the view able to accept any structure.
For example, different arrays of structures for further display of data.
can't see array.
Get ->  var array: T     print("array (array.self)")

Couldn't find a solution to the problem.

```
struct TestStockModel: Decodable {

    let price: String
    let promotionTitle: String
    let image: String

}

class InitStock {

    var testStock: [TestStockModel] = [
        TestStockModel(price: "111.90",
                       promotionTitle: "",
                       image: "paperclip"),
        TestStockModel(price: "222.90",
                       promotionTitle: "",
                       image: "paperclip"),
        TestStockModel(price: "333.90",
                       promotionTitle: "",
                       image: "paperclip"),
    ]

}

struct TestConeiner: View {

    var initModel: InitStock = InitStock()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollBlock(content: TestContentCard(title: "It is title", cart: initModel.testStock))
    }
}

struct ScrollBlock<Content: View>: View {

    var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        content
    }
}

struct TestContentCard<T: Decodable>: View {

    var title: String
    var cart: [T]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            Text(title)
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(0..<cart.count, id: \.self) { element in
                        Text("\(cart[element].self)")
                        .onAppear() {
                                print(cart[element].self)     ?? How this elenement look ?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Element look at whatever is description property can give. If you want generic and have some common property to display, use a generic with a protocol that defines some common properties.